# Allow linked/member account access "Bill details by account"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have done to setup AWS Organizations with 4 accounts (including management account), for example:

```
[management account]
|
----- company-billing
----- company-production
----- company-development
```

From `[management account]`, I am able to view `[Bill details by account]`, please see image below:
[image]

And I wanted the AWS Account named `[company-billing]` also able to see such menu when I do switching role to that account, but unfortunately it's only available to see billing detail for that account only.

Is it possible to archive the goal to see the menu `[Bill details by account]` from linked/member account? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not Possible to see [Bill details by account] through member accounts. You can see [Bill details by account] only through AWS master account.